# Why this filter is not working properly in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this code in VBA:

```
FilterString = "CalanderDate<#" & EndOfWeek(InDate) & "# AND CalanderDate >#" & StartOfWeek(InDate) & "#"
Me.Filter = FilterString
Me.FilterOn = True
```

The code for EndOfWeek and StartOfWeek is as follow:

```
Function StartOfWeek(InDate As Date) As Date
inWeekday = Weekday(InDate, vbMonday)
StartOfWeek = InDate - inWeekday + 1
End Function

Function EndOfWeek(InDate As Date) As Date
EndOfWeek = StartOfWeek(InDate) + 7
End Function
```

The idea is to filter the data based on dates which fall in a specific week ( in the same week and inDate)

But when I run this, I am getting strange behaviour:

If InDate is 2/6/2014, then I have records with the following dates:

```
12/05/2014
21/05/2014
22/05/2014
23/05/2014
```

which none of them fell into the week of 2/6/2014 to 9/6/2014

If I set the inDate to 20/05/2014, I am getting the following records:

```
21/05/2014
22/05/2014
23/05/2014
```

Why the filtering doesn't work properly and how can I fix it?

### Edit1

Deleted as it was wrong. Andy answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CalanderDate<#" & EndOfWeek(InDate) & "# AND CalanderDate >#" & StartOfWeek(InDate) & "#"
```

Access is fussy about the date format and, in particular, reverts to the US format mm/dd/yyyy.

In the above expression use `Format()` with either:

```
Format(EndOfWeek(InDate),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

or

```
Format(EndOfWeek(InDate),"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

and the same for StartOfWeek.

Comment: I don't recognise what you are now asking? Please note that you should not change the original question, any new reader will not be able to follow the answers and comments. Add any additional details below the original question.

Comment: Did you try with `Format()`?